# Referencing the constructor function

Tags: typescript

Im wondering how I can get a reference to a types constructor to pass the function as a value. 
Basically, I would like to have a generic type registry that would allow instances to be created by calling a member function of a generic type registry instance.

For example:

```
class GeometryTypeInfo
{        
    constructor (public typeId: number, public typeName: string, public fnCtor: (...args: any[]) => IGeometry) {
    }
    createInstance(...args: any[]) : IGeometry { return this.fnCtor(args); }
    }
}
```

Later:

```
class Point implements IGeometry {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }

    public static type_info = new GeometryTypeInfo(1, 'POINT', Point); // <- fails
    // also fails: 
    //    new GeometryTypeInfo(1, 'POINT', new Point);
    //    new GeometryTypeInfo(1, 'POINT', Point.prototype);
    //    new GeometryTypeInfo(1, 'POINT', Point.bind(this));
}
```

Anyone know if it is possible to reference a classes constructor function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the constructor type literal or an object type literal with a construct signature to describe the type of a constructor (see, generally, section 3.5 of the language spec). To use your example, the following should work:

```
interface IGeometry {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

class GeometryTypeInfo
{        
    constructor (public typeId: number, public typeName: string, public fnCtor: new (...args: any[]) => IGeometry) {
    }
    createInstance(...args: any[]) : IGeometry { return new this.fnCtor(args); }
}

class Point implements IGeometry {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }

    public static type_info = new GeometryTypeInfo(1, 'POINT', Point);
}
```

Notice the constructor type literal in `GeometryTypeInfo`'s constructor parameter list, and the new call in the implementation of `createInstance`.

Comment: in `// <- fails` I suppose as it's the solution, it doesn't fail anymore, if that's correct maybe you can edit it to `// <- doesn't fail anymore` or something similar? Otherwise it's a bit misleading, thx

Answer (score 10):

`typeof YourClass` gives you constructor *type* which can be used in type annotations.

`YourClass` and `this.constructor` is constructor itself. So, this code compiles:

```
class A {}

const B : typeof A = A;
```

`this.constructor` is not recognized as value of constructor type by TypeScript (which is funny), so in situations like that you need to use some cheating casting it no `any`

`new (<any> this.constructor)()`

That's it.

Comment: The issue with this solution is OP wants to reference the type "constructor of a type that implements an interface", and I believe you can't say `typeof IGeometry` when `IGeometry` is an interface. In the case where the passed param is a constructor for a given class or super class this is a great method.

Comment: `interface MyCtor { new () : MyInterface }` should do the job then.

Comment: But I prefer `typeof Class` whenever possible. It's more specific and handles inheritance chain properly.

Comment: That wouldn't work in this case, since the constructor's signature is `new (x: number, y: number): Point`. And what happens when each class that implements it has a different constructor signature?

Comment: You will need to find some common signature for the subclasses constructors then. Or the type error TypeScript will report will be perfectly valid.

Comment: Cause, polymorphic code you would probably write (class factory, as I understand from the context) would expect the same signature from all the subclasses' constructors.